# Uncomplicated Firewall (UFW) is not blocking anything when using Docker

Tags: 14.04, networking, firewall, ufw, docker

This is my first time setting up an Ubuntu Server (14.04 LTS) and I am having trouble configuring the firewall (UFW).

I only need `ssh` and `http`, so I am doing this:

```
sudo ufw disable

sudo ufw reset
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default allow outgoing

sudo ufw allow 22/tcp
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp

sudo ufw enable
sudo reboot
```

**But I can still connect to databases on other ports of this machine**. Any idea about what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: these databases are on Docker containers. Could this be related? is it overriding my ufw config?

**EDIT2**: output of `sudo ufw status verbose`

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: what database ? which port ? Are you sure this is the same machine ? what is the output of  `ufw status`

Comment: @solsTiCe yes, I am sure it is the same machine. The database is InfluxDB (on a docker container) with ports `8083` and `8086`. I added the `ufw status verbose` output in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

The problem was using the `-p` flag on containers.

It turns out that Docker makes changes directly on your `iptables`, which are not shown with `ufw status`.

Possible solutions are:

1. Stop using the `-p` flag. Use docker linking or [docker networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) instead.
2. Bind containers locally so they are not exposed outside your machine:

   `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 ...`
3. If you insist on using the `-p` flag, tell docker not to touch your `iptables` by disabling them in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and restarting:

   `{ "iptables" : false }`

I recommend option 1 or 2. Beware that option 3 [has side-effects](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/), like containers becoming unable to connect to the internet.

Comment: This is so useful - I was going crazy with being able to access ports I had not allowed in ufw. Using iptables=false breaks a lot though, like containers becoming accessible on localhost, e. g. for reverse proxying. Better to make sure that container listen correct, don't use -p 80:80 but use -p 127.0.0.1:80:80 or different port like 127.0.0.1:3000:80 for reverse proxying with nginx or apache and no port clashes.

Comment: @AndreasReiff you are right, but lately I have found it best to avoid `-p` as much as possible. For example, in the case of a reverse proxy I don't map any port for the worker containers, and then put nginx in it's own container with `-p 80:80` and a `--link` to the others. This way there cannot be any port clashes and the only point of access is through nginx.

Comment: Also check this post for a third precaution you have to take! https://svenv.nl/unixandlinux/dockerufw

Comment: *Important* : `/etc/default/docker` is a configuration file used by the upstart config.
If you have moved from upstart to systemd, this file will not be used.

Comment: @ESala You should think about un-marking this answer as correct since it is dated.

Comment: Why does it work when using `127.0.0.1` but not with `localhost` or `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: Thank you so much! This answer still holds true as of 2021. It was driving me nuts I could access my database from anywhere, but with this answer I finally fixed the problem.

Comment: woah! that's some serious security breach...

Comment: I wonder is there a way to access a port mapped as `127.0.0.1:3000:3000` via ssh tunnel.  

I.e I have a server with public ip where I do not want to expose port 3000 to the Internet, but still want to be able to access it (e.g from my laptop using ssh port forwarding)

Comment: This is a system-wide change that is likely to break functionality of things like reverse proxies where docker SHOULD have access to modify iptables. A better solution would address the specific port only, if possible.

Comment: @ESala do you use NPM if yes, did you bind it to 127..1 and proxy via the actual Nginx server?  I wanted to GEO block IPs of certain countries, and since NPM is a container exposed to 0.0.0.0:80 then blocking IP in UFW won't really prevent that IP from accessing port 80, it will block other ports, by my goal is to block everything

Comment: After that I started to consider usage of ufw.

Answer (score 12):

16.04 presents new challenges. I did all the steps as shown [Running Docker behind the ufw firewall](https://svenv.nl/unixandlinux/dockerufw) **BUT** I could NOT get docker plus UFW to work on 16.04. In other words no matter what I did all docker ports became globally exposed to the internet. Until I found this: [How to set Docker 1.12+ to NOT interfere with IPTABLES/FirewallD](https://web.archive.org/web/20170403124320/http://blog.samcater.com/how-to-set-docker-1-12-to-not-interfere-with-iptables-firewalld/)

I had to create the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and put the following in:

```
{
    "iptables": false
}
```

I then issued `sudo service docker stop` then `sudo service docker start` FINALLY docker is simply following the appropriate rules in UFW.

Additional data: [Docker overrules UFW!](http://chjdev.com/2016/06/08/docker-ufw/)

Comment: With Ubuntu 16.04 and Docker version 17.09, this solution breaks outbound connection from the containers.  See response https://askubuntu.com/a/833363/262702 and https://askubuntu.com/a/954041/262702

Answer (score 7):

If you're using the init system of systemd (Ubuntu 15.10 and later) edit the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (might need to create it if it does not exist), make sure it has `iptables` key configured:

```
{   "iptables" : false }
```

---

**EDIT**: this might cause you to lose connection to the internet from inside containers

If you have UFW enabled, verify that you can access the internet from inside containers. if not - you must define `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY` as `ACCEPT` on `/etc/default/ufw` and apply the trick described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17498195/507564

Answer (score 5):

In my case I've ended up modifying iptables to allow access to Docker only from specific IPs.

As per [ESala's answer](https://askubuntu.com/posts/652572/revisions):

> If you use `-p` flag on containers Docker makes changes directly to iptables, ignoring the ufw.

**Example of records added to iptables by Docker**

Routing to 'DOCKER' chain:

```
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
```

Forwarding packets from 'DOCKER' chain to container:

```
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER ! -i docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6379 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.3:6379
```

**You can modify iptables to allow access to DOCKER chain only from specified source IP (e.g. `1.1.1.1`):**

```
-A PREROUTING -s 1.1.1.1 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT -s 1.1.1.1 ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
```

You may want to use `iptables-save > /tmp/iptables.conf` and `iptables-restore < /tmp/iptables.conf` to dump, edit, and restore iptables rules.

Answer (score 4):

## UPDATE 10.2021

When we use only one port-number then docker will use an ephemeral port
see [docker-compose ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports)

> Specify just the container port (an ephemeral host port is chosen for the host port).

I thought that my original answer worked, because I could not connect to the expected port 1234.
So please don't do this - follow the advice in the other answers.
I will not delete this answer, because it might still be useful to someone to understand why **not** to do this.

## original answer

I used `docker-compose` to start several containers and also had the problem that one port was exposed to the world ignoring ufw rules.

The fix to only make the port available to my docker containers was this change in my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
ports:
- "1234:1234"
```

to this:

```
ports:
- "1234"
```

Now the other docker-containers still can use the port, but I cannot access it from outside.

Comment: This doesn't seem right, as according to the documentation, ["an ephemeral host port is chosen for the host port"](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports). I think it's better to use [expose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#expose) instead.

Answer (score 3):

A fast workaround is when running Docker and doing the port mapping. You can always do

```
docker run ...-p 127.0.0.1:<ext pot>:<internal port> ...
```

to prevent your Docker from being accessed from outside.

Answer (score 2):

Use of `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with content

```
{
  "iptables": false
}
```

might sound like a solution **but it only works until the next reboot**. After that you may notice that none of your containers has access to Internet so you can't for example ping any website. It may be undesired behavior.

Same applies to binding a container to specific IP. You may not want to do that. **The ultimate option is to create a container and have it behind UFW not matter what happens** and how you create this container, so there's a solution:

After you create `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file, invoke:

```
sed -i -e 's/DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="DROP"/DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"/g' /etc/default/ufw
ufw reload
```

so you set up default forward policy in UFW for accept, and use:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o docker0 -s 172.17.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
```

If you're about to use docker-compose, then the IP from command above should be replaced with IP of network docker-compose creates when running it with `docker-compose up`.

I described the problem and solution more comprehensively [in this article](https://www.mkubaczyk.com/2017/09/05/force-docker-not-bypass-ufw-rules-ubuntu-16-04/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use --network=host when you start container so docker will map port to isolated host-only network instead of default bridge network. I see no legal ways to block bridged network. Alternatively you can use custom user-defined network with isolation.

Comment: This solution worked for me - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to your docker console:

   > sudo docker exec -i -t **docker_image_name** /bin/bash
2. And then inside your docker console:

   > ```
   > sudo apt-get update
   > sudo apt-get install ufw
   > sudo ufw allow 22
   > ```
3. Add your ufw rules and enable the ufw

   > sudo ufw enable

   - Your Docker image need to be started with --cap-add=NET_ADMIN

To enable "NET_ADMIN" Docker option:

1.Stop Container:

docker stop yourcontainer;
2.Get container id:

docker inspect yourcontainer;
3.Modify hostconfig.json(default docker path:/var/lib/docker, you can change yours)

```
vim /var/lib/docker/containers/containerid/hostconfig.json
```

4.Search "CapAdd", and modify null to ["NET_ADMIN"];

....,"VolumesFrom":null,"CapAdd":["NET_ADMIN"],"CapDrop":null,....
5.Restart docker in host machine;

service docker restart;
6.Start yourconatiner;

docker start yourcontainer;

Answer (score 0):

**An addition to the accepted answer**

If you map a port like `127.0.0.1:8080:8080` to keep it closed from the Internet, but still want to be able to access it from your working environment (e.g for monitoring/administration/debugging purposes, with IP whitelist or ssh tunnel) there is a "well-known" solution for that:

https://github.com/chaifeng/ufw-docker

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked perfectly for me, and it also doesn't suffer from many of the downsides of the other methods, namely `{ "iptables" : false }` and it disabling internet access from within the containers.

The credit for the solution goes to [tsuna on GitHub](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4737#issuecomment-419705925). It's dead simple, and involves three easy steps:

Open `/etc/ufw/after.rules` in an editor:

```sh
sudo nano /etc/ufw/after.rules
```

Append the following lines to the end of the file (you might need to replace `eth0` with whatever your external facing interface is):

```sh
# Put Docker behind UFW
*filter
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]

-A DOCKER-USER -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-USER -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -j ufw-user-input
-A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Then finally, for the changes to take effect:

```sh
sudo systemctl restart ufw # or `sudo reboot` if this wasn't effective
```